# Node.js: Redirect and send page at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, redirect

I'm trying to build simple server for HTML pages in Node.js. My problem is, when I navigate to (for example) `http://localhost:8080/someDirectory`, browser thinks that someDirectory is file (in reality, it is interally redirected to `someDirectory/index.html`).

So when I do `<script src="./script.js"></script>`, it tries to use `http://localhost:8080/script.js`, instead of `http://localhost:8080/someDirectory/script.js`.

Only solution I can think of is to redirect browser to `/someDirectory/` (with slash at the end). Then, the browser correctly understands that it is directory and not file.

My problem is, I don't want to make my server slow, because of double request (client gets redirected, sends another request, and then finally gets the webpage). Is there any posibility to send send page and just notify the browser of change, instead of using 302 header to redirect?

---

EDIT: When I visit some page running on Apache server, when I enter `http://localhost/someDirectory`, the trailing slash get automatically appended. I'm just curious how it is done (no additional PHP or javascript).

Comment: Use express.js to handle serving html

Comment: Are those just typos, or did you actually use `http:/...` rather than `http://`?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible, and wouldn't even be the right solution.  You can certainly send content with a redirect, but it's pointless because the browser won't display it... it will immediately follow the redirect.

If you want `/someDirectory/`, that is different than `/someDirectory`.  You must redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `history.replaceState` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method)).  This will work in most modern browsers (most users) but not in older browsers.  Since older browsers are dwindling, it should become less of a problem as time moves on. This should do the trick - you will need to paste it directly in your HTML markup for this to work:

```
if ( !window.location.pathname.match(/\/$/) ) {
    if ( window.history && window.history.replaceState ) {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname + '/');
        document.write('<script src="./script.js"></script>');
    } else
        window.location.replace( window.location.pathname + '/');
} else {
    document.write('<script src="./script.js"></script>');
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, for SEO reasons.  You would have to serve the same content for both URLs.  In addition, you still have a lot of compatibility issues.\

Comment: The server should already serve the same content for either URL, the "canonical" tag would solve any duplicity concerns, the "worst" compatibility issue is that older browsers will do a redirect. In the case where all the hyperlink URLs on the site for some reason don't end in a slash, you're reducing redirects by almost 50%... which is good for SEO and less work for the server.

Comment: I disagree strongly.  The server should **not** serve the same content for either URL (unless of course that is your intention, which is not standard behavior).  These sort of redirects really don't need to happen unless you have users keying in URLs.  If you link to the right thing in the first place, this isn't an issue for speed.

Comment: Trailing slashes have always been one of those optional (often configurable) things which you implement based [mainly] on preference.  Like it or not, most servers do not implement "strict" URL paths by default... serving up the same content regardless of trailing slashes.  I just tested Apache, IIS, and node (express)...

Comment: Right, and what do all of those servers do?  302 redirect.

Comment: Nope, 200 OK responses on all of them.  Event this website does this same.  Try it, put a slash up there...  302 responses are deliberate and implemented based on preference.  It seems you prefer "strict" urls, the rest of the world defaults to "loose"

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/298408/EN-US

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55802/discussion-between-ryan-wheale-and-brad).